# source won't change the package path

Tags: ros, source, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to run the pcl tutorial, since i need it for an university project.

Unfortunately when I try to run the exaple

```
arnold@arnold-UX31E:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun my_pcl_tutorial example input:=/camera/depth/points
```

I get the error back:

> [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named example below /home/arnold/catkin_ws/src/my_pcl_tutorial

The executable crated with `catkin_make` is in the build folder, not in src (this seams to be correct).
But `rosrun` trys to run it from the src folder. A little research came to the conclusion that it isn't sourced right.
When I run
`arnold@arnold-UX31E:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.sh`  I get no response (no error or approval) and nothing changes.

I already deleted the workspace 3 times and just followed the instructions from this Tutorials.
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace and http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials

Running Ros Indigo under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

---

Answer to the first Comments, My Input:
[image: image description]

Return of a fresh `catkin_make` build:

```
arnold@arnold-UX31E:~$ printenv | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros

arnold@arnold-UX31E:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/arnold/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/arnold/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/arnold/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/arnold/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/arnold/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/arnold/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/arnold/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/arnold/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/arnold/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/arnold/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/arnold/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/arnold/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/arnold/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.19
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - my_pcl_tutorial
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'my_pcl_tutorial'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(my_pcl_tutorial)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/arnold/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/arnold/catkin_ws/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target example
[100%] Building CXX object my_pcl_tutorial/CMakeFiles/example.dir/src/example.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable example
[100%] Built target example
```

Content `CMakeLists.txt`: Altered like described in the tutorial.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_pcl_tutorial)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pcl_conversions
  pcl_ros
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
)
add_executable(example src/example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   sensor_msgs
# )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES my_pcl_tutorial
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS pcl_conversions pcl_ros roscpp sensor_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/my_pcl_tutorial.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
# add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/my_pcl_tutorial_node.cpp)

## Rename C++ executable without prefix
## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_my_pcl_tutorial.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264390/source-won%27t-change-the-package-path/) by [Arnold](https://answers.ros.org/users/30850/arnold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:\

> When I run
> `arnold@arnold-UX31E:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.sh`  I get no response (no error or approval) and nothing changes.

That is expected, as it only updates your environment variables.

Please post the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and tell us how you created your workspace.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
And the *exact* order in which you `source`, `catkin_make` and `rosrun` things.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
And just noticed this:

if you are using `bash` as your shell, you should use the `setup.bash` file, *not* the `setup.sh`.

**Comment by [Arnold](https://answers.ros.org/users/30850/arnold/) on 2017-06-22**:
Ok, I'm going to edit the exact order and results into the first post. I created the workspace how it was shown in the catkin create_a_workspace tutorial.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
Can you first try to `source devel/setup.bash`? It might be that is all you did 'wrong'.

**Comment by [Arnold](https://answers.ros.org/users/30850/arnold/) on 2017-06-22**:
posted my log as picture in the first post.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
Please don't use images for what is essentially text - you can just copy-paste from a terminal into your question text.

As to the output: I don't see any CMake output indicating that it's building any executable binaries. Can you include the `CMakeLists.txt` of the pkg you created?

**Comment by [Arnold](https://answers.ros.org/users/30850/arnold/) on 2017-06-22**:
Thats because the pkg was already build. If i delete the build folder and rerun `catkin_make`. It returns another text where it build a hack of more stuff. I'm wondering because the last last line `Linking CXX executable example` is red for me. I can't upload a file because i don't have 5 karma.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
The binary seems to be built, so that is good. Could you just copy-paste the contents of the `CMakeLists.txt` into your question? It should not be too many lines - just make sure to not include all the comments.

You don't have anything in `devel/lib`?

**Comment by [Arnold](https://answers.ros.org/users/30850/arnold/) on 2017-06-22**:
I posted the whole `catkin_make` report. If you need the `CMakeLists.txt` i can post you the content. Wish i could use spoilers her to organize my post.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:\

> [..] just make sure to not include all the comments.

Comments are all lines starting with a `#`. With your `CMakeLists.txt` that would reduce the nr of lines significantly ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ..
>
> add_executable(example src/example.cpp)
> ```

```
target_link_libraries(example ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

> ```
> ...
> ```

```
catkin_package(
   ...
)
```

Please move the `add_executable(..)` and `target_link_libraries(..)` lines *below* the `catkin_package(..)` line. Delete your `build` and `devel` folders and rebuild your workspace. That should make things work.

This is slightly unintuitive, but it is documented. See [wiki/catkin - CMakeLists.txt - Overall Structure and Ordering](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Overall_Structure_and_Ordering) on the ROS wiki.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arnold](https://answers.ros.org/users/30850/arnold/) on 2017-06-22**:
Thanks, this worked.

Now I'm getting another error, when I `rosrun my_pcl_tutorial example input:=/camera/depth/points`

```
[ERROR] [1498134195.591725742]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...
```

but this is another error and I'm trying it on my own first.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
Good to hear that resolved it.

As to your next problem: you simply need to start a `roscore` first.